# Error while configuring Entity data source

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting the following error while configuring Entity data source,I already have EF6 installed,as  mentioned in the error what/how should I edit in the mark-up to get rid of this erro?

Error:-

[image]

Entity Framework6 installed:-

[image]

Markup:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="font-family:Arial"">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:EntityDataSource>
     </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should edit the markup. Period. Not to get rid of the error. The wizard doesn't support higher versions.

Comment: @GertArnold - my question is how should I edit the markup?

Comment: Also,as shown in the screen shot I already installed EF6 compatible Microsoft ASP.net Entity Data source ,why is it still throwing an error?